# What complex numbers satisfy $\lvert z-1 \rvert \lvert z+1 \rvert <3$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value

What complex numbers satisfy $\lvert z-1 \rvert \lvert z+1 \rvert< 3$?

The set of complex numbers satisfying $\lvert z-1 \rvert=r$ for $r$ a positive real number is the open disc centered at $1$ with radius $r$. How to proceed? Is this set connected?

Comment: Multiply $|z-1||z+1|$ and consider $u=z^2$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Can the constraint be simplified from $|z^2 - 1| < 3$?

Comment: Yes. We are (non-rigorously) taking the square root of a complex disc, and results in the contour Parcly Taxel describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of curve where the product of distances to two fixed points is constant is called a [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval). It is not an ellipse, though looks like one if the constant is at least $2$.

Since you wrote an inequality, the set of satisfying points is everything strictly within the oval.

Comment: this is pretty neat

Comment: It sure is.....